# Issue with SSH Key while upgrading Gitlab 11 -> 14

Tags: gitlab

I would appreciate your assistance. I upgraded an old Gitlab 11.9.4 instance to Gitlab 14.1.x (all using dockers), I have gone through all the upgrade path and middle versions that are required and everything is working rather smoothly.

The only issue I am encountering is that users that connected to my Gitlab using SSH are now getting an error of "Remote Host Identification has Changed" and "Possible DNS Spoofing Detected".
I am at a loss to why is it happening because I copied all the keys from my old /etc/ssh dir to the new one.

I read about the suggestions to delete the known_hosts files, I would like to avoid that. I did try it just to see what the difference is and it seems that in the new Gitlab instance, the "hostname" that I get in the known_hosts file is composed of both the hostname and the IP in the next format: `"<hostname>,<ip> ...."`.
This is in contrast to the older gitlab instance where the hostname in known_hosts is just the `<hostname>` -  I assume this might be the issue.

Has anyone has encountered this issue? Would really appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm. Did you change servers or upgrade in-place? I don't think GitLab stores its key in `/etc/ssh`. It stores it in the home of the `git` user, which is by default in `/var/opt/gitlab`. As long as you persist `/var/opt/gitlab` this shouldn't be an issue as far as I know. I use GitLab Omnibus in docker and we do not mount/persist `/etc/ssh` and don't have this issue with upgrades, FWIW.

Comment: Hi sytech. We upgraded in place. We did transfer the .ssh dir in /var/opt/gitlab as well. No change of IPs has been done. Really odd and I really can't find much info about it.

Comment: You may be able to remove the offending entry in your ~/.ssh/known_hosts file via `ssh-keygen -R old.gitlab.instance.name` and then you can add the new proper entry via `ssh-keyscan -H new.gitlab.instance.name >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50628840/possible-dns-spoofing-detected-remote-host-identification-has-changed may also provide more info.